# Environment Variable not set: ARCHS

Tags: ios, environment-variables, applescript, xcode12, apple-m1

> Environment Variable not set: ARCHS
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Getting this error while building a project. But intel based system working fine.

System Configuration:

- Apple M1
- Big Sur-11.2.3
- XCODE-12.4.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am having a similar issue. Thanks!